# Joomla Date Picker

Tags: php, html, joomla, datetimepicker

I am attempting to run this syntax inside of an article - but it just spits the results out on screen.  What is the proper way to add a Date Picker to a Joomla article?

**Long term goal here is to capture the date selected and use it in a query that runs on button press.

```
JHTML::_(‘behavior.calendar’);
<input type=”text” name=”startdate”
id=”startdate” size=”30" maxlength=”30"/>
<input type=”reset” value=”…”
onclick=”return showCalendar(‘startdate’,'%Y-%m-%d’);” />
```

Comment: i don't think it's even allowed in articles :/ can't you just use select ?

Comment: @Axcel - Select?  How would I do such?

Comment: in the editor there is a HTML button go for it and just use a simple html structure you can even use Jquery as i read in their documentation but as i said the code you wrote there is dedicated for component development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is possible using the new 'custom fields' feature of Joomla 3.7.

First step would be to upgrade to the latest version of Joomla assuming that this is possible for your setup.

Then under Content > Fields create a new field using the 'Calendar' option.

Now when you go to add a new article under the 'fields' tab is the option to add a date which will be displayed on the article.

Does that help?

Comment: That sounds perfect.  Let me check which version of Joomla I am running.

Comment: I did in fact upgrade to Joomla 3.7 and this is working exactly as I need!